# How to find in map the pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, dictionary

I have two container std::map; 
How to remove data from a container containing pointers to objects, knowing the pointer (address)?

```
std::map<K, CacheEntry<T>> values_;
std::map<CacheEntry<T>*, K> timeMap_;
```

How i can find item in timeMap_?

```
CacheEntry<T> tmp(value);
values_.insert(std::make_pair(key, tmp));
timeMap_.insert(std::make_pair(&tmp, key));
deleteFromTimeMap(&tmp);
```

And **deleteFromTimeMap**:

```
void deleteFromTimeMap(const CacheEntry<T>* findItem)
            {
                details::LockGuard lk(mutex_);
                auto it = timeMap_.find(findItem); //Error
                timeMap_.erase(it);
            }
```

Comment: So what is the error? Please post an MCVE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

map::erase can accept a key type, like this:

```
void deleteFromTimeMap(const CacheEntry<T>* findItem)
            {
                details::LockGuard lk(mutex_);
                timeMap_.erase(findItem);
            }
```

see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/erase/

and , according to my understanding , in this code:

```
CacheEntry<T> tmp(value);
values_.insert(std::make_pair(key, tmp));
timeMap_.insert(std::make_pair(&tmp, key));
deleteFromTimeMap(&tmp);
```

you want timeMap_ 's key be a pointer point to a CacheEntry object in values_ , right ?
but since std::make_pair() and map::insert() constructs new object , so timeMap_ 's key does not point to object in values_, instead it point to the stack object tmp , after tmp is destructed , key in timeMap_ is Dangling pointer , this is dangerous.

maybe , what you need is this:

```
CacheEntry<T> tmp(value);
values_.insert(std::make_pair(key, tmp));
timeMap_.insert(std::make_pair(&values[key], key));
deleteFromTimeMap(&tmp);
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your map stores non-const pointers, but you're trying to erase a const one.  Just remove `const` from the `deleteFromTimeMap` signature.